# Как организовать поиск в базе на сайте?

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет.
Вот не могу немного разобраться с поиском.
Пишу запрос, используя LIKE.

Если написать так:

> select * from 'table' where 'pole1'
> like 'searchstr'

ничего не выдаст

Если написать так:

> select * from 'table' where 'pole1'
> like '%searchstr%'

выдает все записи таблицы.

Что делать? как исправить запрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from 'table' where 'pole1' like 'searchstr'
```

Вот так он ищет в БД ровно то, что Вы вводите. Если отличается хоть на 1 знак, то не найдет. То есть, например, если есть название "Сайт №1", а Вы вводите просто "Сайт", он не найдет.

```
select * from 'table' where 'pole1' like '%searchstr%'
```

Вот это ищет в БД такую строку, где хоть как-то присутствует то, что Вы вводите для поиска. То есть если есть "Сайт №1", Вы введете хотя бы "ай", он это найдет.

Вам-то что надо?

Comment: не успела написать что все норм, вопросы сама удалять пока не могу просто... Нашла ошибку. Все норм